# Which minifig is this?

Tags: minifigure-identification

I have this minifig in a set I bought. But I cannot identify it.

Does anyone know which one this is?

[image]

Answer (score 16):

A few image searches can identify the components of the minifig.

Helmet is [part x164](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x164), AKA "star wars rebel helmet" in plain light bley. It's Luke Skywalker's alternate headpiece in two millenium falcons ([set 7965](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7965-1), [set 75192](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75192-1)).

[image: helmet]

As pointed out by fellow user Sander De Dycker, the head is [part 3626cpb0817](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb0817). It appears in more than 100 Star Wars sets, most of the time as part of an imperial stormtrooper.

[image: head]

Torso is [part 973pb1944c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1944c01), AKA "Ultron Prime torso", which appears only in [set 76031](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76031-1).

[image: torso]

Legs are [part 970c00pb0316](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=970c00pb0316) AKA "Ezra Bridger's legs" (a character from "Star Wars: Rebels"). It appears in three star wars sets.

[image: legs]

Comment: whow, I didn't see that one coming. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Nicely found - to complete the ensemble, the head looks like [Minifigure, Head Black Eyebrows, Cheek Lines, Chin Dimple, Grimacing Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb0817).

Comment: @asusk7m550 You're welcome! Since you're new, let me remind you of https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers - if the answer is satisfactory, then it's customary to "accept" the answer.

Comment: It looks like Rando Calrissian to me.